# Elastic search - search_after parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

I read this [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-request-search-after.html) to understand 'search_after' and have two question.

1. I'm curious that where "tweet#654323" comes from. Is this one of
   document id or field data?
2. When I added multiple parameter of search_after, Is that 'and'
       condition or 'or' condition?

   ex) "search_after": [1463538857, 5147821]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. As mentioned in that doc, `"tweet#654323"` is the `_uid` value of the document, which is made up of the `_type` and the `_id` of the document.
2. You need as many values in `search_after` as you have `sort` clauses and those values must be ordered the same way as in your sort clause. In `"search_after": [1463538857, 5147821]`, it looks like you're sorting by a date field and some other id field.

Comment: One more question. How can I understand with uid order? I understood that id is made randomly when I don't specify it. Is id made with some insert order?

Comment: If you don't specify the ID, it is generated in a random manner. Taking two documents with randomly generated ids, you cannot deduct which one was indexed first solely based on such a random ID.